# Error placing a static image with OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

Working with the last version of OpenLayers 3, I'm not able to load correctly a static image over the map. After some test (with similar configuration) I found that the image looks fine on OL2, while on OL3 it has a displacement of several kilometers, as you can see on the following image:

[image]

I've done a plunker with that example. Could it be a bug or I'm missing something? http://plnkr.co/lzAKNGdkXkz6ZCM9H6ml

```
/* OL3 */
  var graphicOL3 = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
      url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VictorVelarde/ImagenEstuario/master/Composite.png',
      imageSize: [864, 1024],
      imageExtent: [-791350.472638389, 5376837.581117962, -778150.4726383891, 5398392.773800777]
    })
  });
  var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });
  mapaOL3 = new ol.Map({
    layers: [osm],
    target: 'mapaOL3',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-784751.048, 5389384.957],
      zoom: 13
    })
  });
  mapaOL3.addLayer(graphicOL3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a bug of OL3 library. They resolved it on this ticket: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4426 It´s not yet implemented on the last release version (3.11.2) so if you face this problem you have to point to the master: http://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js